# Kivy window not changing size on android

Tags: python, kivy

So the app works fine on windows but after compiling it to android through buildozer, trying to run it produces a black screen and logcat returns this error on startup:

```
[SurfaceView[kcb_sinner.kcb/org.kivy.android.PythonActivity]#1]9f:0,a:0) rejecting buffer:active_size=720x1280, requested_size=720x1280 buffer{size=720x1184 transform=0}
```

My code:

```
import sqlite3
from curse import Recipe
from kivy.config import Config
Config.set("graphics","width","700")
Config.set("graphics","height","200")
Config.write()
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.properties import get_color_from_hex
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager
from functools import partial

connection = sqlite3.connect("recipes.db")
cursor = connection.cursor()
recipe_get = cursor.execute("""
SELECT id,name FROM recipes
ORDER BY name
""")

class ScreenMan(ScreenManager):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

class MainWindow(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.name = "acertainmagical"
        self.add_widget(RecIndex())

class RecIndex(ScrollView):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.layout = BoxLayout(orientation="vertical",spacing=5,size_hint=(1,None))
        self.layout.bind(minimum_height=self.layout.setter("height"))
        self.add_widget(self.layout)

        for re in recipe_get:
            if recipe_get:
                button = Button(text=re[1], size_hint=(1, None),opacity=1)
                button.bind(on_release=partial(self.go_to_deets, re[0]))
                self.layout.add_widget(button)
            else:
                self.layout.add_widget(
                    Label(text="No Recipes Found",pos_hint={"center_x":.5,"center_y":.5},size_hint=(.2,.2),opacity=1))

    def go_to_deets(self,key,inst):
        app = App.get_running_app()
        app.root.transition.direction = "left"
        app.root.current = "details"
        app.root.get_screen("details").get_det(key)

class SecondWindow(Screen):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.name = "details"
        self.layout = BoxLayout(orientation="vertical")
        self.add_widget(self.layout)

    def back_to_main(self,inst):
        app = App.get_running_app()
        app.root.transition.direction = "right"
        app.root.current = "acertainmagical"
        self.layout.clear_widgets()

    def get_det(self,key):
        recipe = Recipe()
        recipe.load_from_db(key)

        rec_label = Label(text=recipe.name,size_hint=(.15,.2),pos_hint={"center_x":.5,"center_y":.5})
        rec_meal = Label(text=recipe.meal_type,size_hint=(.15,.2),pos_hint={"center_x":.5,"center_y":.5})
        rec_ingr = TextInput(text=recipe.directions,readonly=True,background_color=get_color_from_hex("#000000"),
                             foreground_color=get_color_from_hex("#F0F0F0"),halign="left")
        rec_steps = Label(text=recipe.ingredients)
        back_button = Button(text="Back",size_hint=(1,.2),on_release=partial(self.back_to_main),opacity=1)

        self.layout.add_widget(rec_label)
        self.layout.add_widget(rec_meal)
        self.layout.add_widget(rec_steps)
        self.layout.add_widget(rec_ingr)
        self.layout.add_widget(back_button)

class KCBApp(App):
    def build(self):
        sm = ScreenMan()
        sm.add_widget(MainWindow())
        sm.add_widget(SecondWindow())

        return sm


if __name__ == "__main__":
    KCBApp().run()
```

Any help would be appreciated.

I've tried adjusting the config and using Window.size to adjust the screen but it's the same no matter what.

Comment: Try moving the `Config` stuff to before any other imports. If `Config.set()` is called too late, it will have no effect.

Comment: No changes unfortunately.